# Set android emulator device name

Tags: android-emulator, adb, appium, emulation, genymotion

When I connect my phone to the computer and use `adb devices` in console I can see:

```
List of devices attached
XYZQWERTYXYZ device
```

When I connect same phone to another pc, the device name stays the same.

Recently I starded using [MEMU](https://www.memuplay.com/) emulator. When I run android instance via emulator `adb devices` returns something like this:

```
List of devices attached
127.0.0.1:21513 device
```

The problem is when I want to use same memu android instance on another pc. I can export and import that instance, but the device name can be different on another pc, like:

```
List of devices attached
127.0.0.1:21503 device
```

I found configuration file in `D:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu\MemuHyperv VMs\MEmu_1` location which contains configs for each emulator android instance. In `.memu` files I can find lines such:

```
<Forwarding name="ADB" proto="1" hostip="127.0.0.1" hostport="21513" guestip="10.0.2.15" guestport="5555"/>
<Forwarding name="MVD" proto="1" hostip="127.0.0.1" hostport="21511" guestip="10.0.2.15" guestport="21501"/>
```

I thought I can force memu to run android instance on specific port by changing the `hostport` to different value, like

```
<Forwarding name="ADB" proto="1" hostip="127.0.0.1" hostport="21600" guestip="10.0.2.15" guestport="5555"/>
```

Unfortunelly when I start android instance via MEMU, the hostport goes back to `21513`. Is there anything I can about that?

In other words - **I would like to have opportunity to determine device name.**

Comment: @a_local_nobody It matters.

Comment: @a_local_nobody I wrote software to automate stuff on my phone using `appium`. I can easy switch to another pc and run that software (which requires setting device name). I can't do that if device name changes.

Comment: ah ok, that's fair, was just wondering if this is even a problem

Comment: I'm looking a solution to this too. My current workaround is to open the text file and find the host port corresponds to guestport="5555"

Answer (score 1):

Tested with latest Memu, it seems that Memu will revert hostport every startup, by design.

A simple workaround is forwarding port with Windows firewall, like this:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=21600 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=21513 connectaddress=localhost
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port for Memu_0" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=21600
```